# Azure Web App HTTP Response size limitations?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have an Web API hosted on Azure at the moment, when we get a large response back (250MB+) it does not send the response back but the status code is 200. On our local we get the JSON response back successfully, we believe there is a response limit set on Azure.

If possible how can we increase this limit?

Answer (score 0):

```
If possible how can we increase this limit?
```

You can try to add this code in your web.config file to increase the size of the response:

```cs
<configuration> 
       <system.web.extensions>
           <scripting>
               <webServices>
                   <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
               </webServices>
           </scripting>
       </system.web.extensions>
    </configuration>
```

`Response` does not have any limit. We can limit the **response size** by adding a parameter called as `Content-Length` into the response header.

To increase **request size** you put the below code into `web.config`:

```cs
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how to set the <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/> in asp core .Net5? I did try adding AddNewtonsoftJson to my controllers but that also did not help.

Comment: refer this SO thread--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config/12278956#12278956 to set that.

Comment: This hasn't resolved my issue, I believe there is a limit set on Azure which one cannot change